# jQuery execute multiple functions only on focus. 2 Problems

Tags: jquery, setinterval, onfocus

I found many codes for executing multiple functions every second only when the window is on focus but they are either not working or not working right. For example this code:

```
<div id="test""></div>
<br>
<div id="test2"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var interval_id;
$(window).focus(function() {
    if (!interval_id)
        interval_id = setInterval(stuff1, 1000);
        interval_id = setInterval(stuff2, 1000);
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    clearInterval(interval_id);
    interval_id = 0;
});



function stuff1(){
    $("#test").append("1" + " ");
}
function stuff2(){
    $("#test2").append("2" + " ");
}
</script>
```

So I want `stuff1` and `stuff2` to be executed every second. 
Problem 1:
It don't start when I call the page first time, I need to open another page/hide this page and return to it so the functions start.

Problem 2:
When I return to this page second time `stuff1` is getting executed twice as fast, so every 0.5 seconds, on third time 0.33 seconds and so on. What is wrong here and how can I do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Maybe you need to call the function on `.ready()` (or `.load()`) too
2. `clearInterval()` is called only on stuff2. Use different interval_id for both of them.

Created a snippet for you:

```js
var interval_id;
$(window).focus(function() {
  if (!interval_id) {
    interval_id1 = setInterval(stuff1, 1000);
    interval_id2 = setInterval(stuff2, 1000);
  }
});

$(window).blur(function() {
  clearInterval(interval_id1);
  clearInterval(interval_id2)
  interval_id1 = interval_id2 = 0;
});

function stuff1() {
  $("#test").append("1" + " ");
}

function stuff2() {
  $("#test2").append("2" + " ");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" style="margin-top: 40px;"></div>
<br>
<div id="test2" style="margin-top: 40px;"></div>
```

Comment: Well it sucks that I need to run the functions somewhere seperate for the first pageload